# How to display user's phone number in Joomla 3.2 frontend

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm building a community website using Joomla 3.2, and I would like to display users' phone numbers and city in the front-end.

I'm using this code to call these info from the database

```
<span class="contact-mobile">
  <?php echo JText::sprintf('USER_PHONE','<a href="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=profile'.($itemId?'&Itemid='.$itemId:'')).'"><span>'.$infoUser -> phone.'<span></a>');?>
</span>
<span class="city">
  <?php echo JText::sprintf('USER_CITY','<a href="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=profile'.($itemId?'&Itemid='.$itemId:'')).'"><span>'.$infoUser -> city.'<span></a>');?>
</span>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can someone please show me how to make it work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is this ``$infoUser object``. Is it user object? Something from another component? You have to give much more informations.

Comment: $infoUser object comes from Pinboard component. It's a free component developped by Templaza and can be found at [link]https://github.com/templaza/tz_pinboard. I've tried to replace it by <?php echo $Pins->telephone; ?> with no succes. But I managed to get the username when I used this code: <?php echo $Pins->user_name; ?>

Comment: First of all use print_r or var_dump on infoUser to see what variables does this object provide. I'm not familiar with this component.